# which multi-touch hardware devices are programmable via Adobe AIR 2?

Tags: flex3, air, flex4

Thank you for your interesting in my question. You can help me out from this little problem.

I am looking to buy the new hardware that is appropriate to use as development machine for multi-touch feature in Adobe AIR 2. I found HP TouchSmart series, which used in Mr.Kevin's demonstration in Adobe MAX 2009, is too expansive for me.

[alt text http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/c02008173.jpg](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/c02008173.jpg)

So I found a standalone HP monitor, 2209t, which describe about 'can multi-touch' but I don't sure is its feature is completed like the TouchSmart series. The documentation show it can detect "multi-touch zoom" but how about "2 finger rotation"? I also called to HP support. But as you guess, they have no any information for this.

Please help me out from this problem. I think it would be very nice if we and Adobe can form an official list of hardwares that is appropriate for Adobe AIR developer.

Thank you for any advice or suggestion.

Document link: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02005883&tmp_task=useCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=4053314&lang=en

Comment: This is programming related.  Perhaps the better question is "which multi-touch hardware devices are programmable via Adobe AIR".

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I updated the question following your advice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the full official list, but it's work a look at

[multitouch presentation slides http://theflashblog.com/presentations/multitouch.html_files/multitouch.015.jpg](http://theflashblog.com/presentations/multitouch.html_files/multitouch.015.jpg)

[Lee Brimelow's FITC 2010 Multitouch Presentation](http://theflashblog.com/presentations/multitouch.html). ( slide 16 onwards )

More AIR 2.0 stuff, but not relevant to this question:

[Christian Cantrell's Exhaustive List of AIR 2.0 features](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/everything_new_in_air_2.html)